# resistance of a wire connected circular

Tags: ohms

If a wire of 5ohms resistance connected in circular and at any two points if we connect a multimeter it will reads 1.25ohms,like that one of my sir told me that,is that true?if yes why it will show like that?

Comment: Nope, only if the connections are opposite one another, then it's 2.5 ohms on each side.  Any other points (that are not opposite) will lead to less resistance... think about what happens if they are right next to each other.

Comment: Actually he explained me for the 1.25ohm answer like this.when we connect any resistive material in circular manner then by connecting any meauring meter for reistance it will supply some current through it and the current will divide at the two ends of the measuring device hence it will show 1.25ohm like that he said is that correct or not please explain me george

Comment: His explanation is only right if the two points are on exactly opposite sides.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Imagine a circle. It's length is \$L=2\pi r\$. Now assume we are choosing two points on the circle, such that it is dividing the length to two arcs, one of the length \$L_1=2\pi r t\$ and  \$L_2=2\pi r (1-t)\$, where \$t\$ is a general parameter defining the ratio between two lengths (and defined between \$0\$ and \$1\$, inclusive). So, when we connect a multimeter between the two points, we are getting the two lines connected in **parallel**, so the resistance would be proportional to $$L_1||L_2=\frac{(2\pi r)(2\pi r)t(1-t)}{2\pi r (t+1-t)} = 2\pi r\ t(1-t)$$
So, if the whole wire is \$5\Omega\$, but we want to get \$1.25\Omega\$, which is \$1/4\$ of it, we should solve $$t(1-t)=1/4$$
which is giving \$t=0.5\$. I.e. the points have to be on the opposite sides of the circle's diameter, thus dividing it's length by two.

**Update:** Actually the above calculation will be true for any closed shape of length \$L\$, not only circle, of course. We can just omit the explicit \$L\$ calculation and write \$L_1=L t\$ and  \$L_2=L(1-t)\$
and thus $$L_1||L_2=\frac{L^2t(1-t)}{L (t+1-t)} = L t(1-t)$$

Comment: Thank you eugene,it makes me better understand.and it will be very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are measuring the resistance of the multimeter's tip?
If you had a small resistance, the contact resistance of the multimeter is not trascurable. You need to use the offset function of your multimeter to put internal resistance to zero (if I understood what do you have done).